# Docker running with localhost but not with domain name - How to assign domain names to containers in docker - windows 10

Tags: docker, dns, angular5, cross-domain, hosts

I have assigned two domain name to access the cookies.

In docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      proxy:
        image: nginx:1.11
        ports:
          - '81:80'
        volumes:
          - ./proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      dashboard:
        build: ./dashboard/ddsp
        volumes:
          - ./dashboard/ddsp:/app
      project:
        build: ./project/ddsp
        volumes:
          - ./project/ddsp:/app
```

In default.conf

```
    server {
        server_name dashboard.iot.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://dashboard:4200/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
    server {
        server_name project.iot.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://project:4200/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
```

In proxy hosts

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost dashboard.iot.com project.iot.com
```

In systems/drivers/etc/hosts also i tried

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost dashboard.iot.com project.iot.com
```

Inthis I can access the cookies from **.iot.com** domain only. So I have named the dashboard and my project with **.oit.com** domain name.

Both are (dashboard and project) are created as different project.

When I try with URL **localhost:81** its running and login successfully but not redirecting to dashboard since the cookies is not set.

but If try the URL **dashboard.iot.com** I got error **"Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 
Your requested host "dashboard.iot.com"** could not be resolved by DNS."

Any configuration is missing?

And this configuration **working in MAC machine** with proxy port

```
    ports:
          - '80:80'
```

But **not working in Windows 10** with **port 81:80** (also tried with 80:80)

Comment: do you have an exception in your browser for the URL?

Comment: @Gabbax0r No I dont have

Comment: try it without proxy or with an exception under your proxy settings.

Comment: @Gabbax0r Its working without proxy. Thanks a lot.,